# Why does page.setViewport not accurately set the width and height of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm trying to generate a pdf from a webpage. Now as you can see in the image I added, I would like to generate a pdf from the element that is surrounded by a red border.

I thought I could make this work by setting the elements' `width` and `height` to `595px` and `842px` on the frontend and the viewport to `await page.setViewport({ width: 595, height: 842, deviceScaleFactor: 1 });`.

Why does the generated pdf contain all that unnecessary whitespace? And how can I generate a pdf that fits the entire element?

Just for clarification, I cannot use `page.setContent` as a lot of the data will be dynamic and I also have to preserve the CSS.

My full code:

```
async function generatePDF() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 595, height: 842, deviceScaleFactor: 1 });
    await page.goto("http://localhost:8080", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    const options = {
        path: "invoice.pdf",
        pageRanges: '1',
        format: "a4",
        printBackground: true,
    }
    await page.pdf(options);
    await browser.close();
}
```

[image: example pdf]

Answer (score 0):

`pdf` doesn't rely on the viewport. It doesn't work like the `screenshot` function, it works more like a print action, which depends on the paper size.

You could try passing the `height` and `width` to the `pdf` function:

```js
const options = {
    path: "invoice.pdf",
    pageRanges: '1',
    width: "595px",
    height: "842px",
    printBackground: true,
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't change anything either. It looks like the ONLY thing that influences how the pdf looks is the width and height on the frontend, correct?. Setting the elements' width and hight on the frontend to `790px` and `1117px` resulted in the following pdf: https://gyazo.com/964f661a02f0cb9806fb2d5d4649d573 . I don't understand these arbitrary numbers lol. Do you know a different way by any chance?